# Kernel of morphism from polynomial ring over field, to some ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

In the book "Undergraduate Commutative Algebra" by Reid, there appears the following supposedly very easy exercise 0.5:

[image]

Why isn't the ring $A$ of diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices over (for instance) $\mathbb{C}$, with $\alpha$ the matrix $\text{diag} \left(1,0\right)$, not a counter example? (i.e. because our $f$ is the polynomial $\left(T-1\right)T$ which is reducible.)

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like there is an intended assumption that $A$ is actually a domain (or maybe that assumption is stated in the text above somewhere).

Comment: It doesn't seem like such an assumption appears somewhere, but it does indeed solve the problem. I guess that was the intention... Thank you!